# Why aren't operator conversions implicitly called for templated functions? (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, implicit

I have the following code:

```
template <class T>
struct pointer
{
  operator pointer<const T>() const;
};


void f(pointer<const float>);

template <typename U>
void tf(pointer<const U>);

void g()
{
  pointer<float> ptr;
  f(ptr);
  tf(ptr);
}
```

When I compile the code with gcc 4.3.3 I get a message (`aaa.cc:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘tf(pointer<float>&)’`) indicating that the compiler called `'operator pointer<const T>'` for the non-templated function f(), but didn't for the templated function tf(). Why and is there any workaround short of overloading tf() with a const and non-const version?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: perhaps the stackoverflow software is removing your template angle brackets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that you don't get implicit type conversions during template deduction, it never gets to that point.

Consider:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {};

template <typename U>
void bar(foo<U>)
{}

foo<int> f;
bar(f);
```

For that call to bar, the compiler can deduce that `U` is an `int`, and instantiate the function. However, consider:

```
template <typename U>
void bar(foo<const U>)
{}  // note  ^^^^

foo<int> f;
bar(f);
```

There is no `U` the compiler can deduce such that the type of `foo` matches the type of the parameter. Ergo, template instantiation fails. There is no chance for the conversion to happen.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename U>
void tf(pointer<const float>);
```

^ The compiler won't match a function call to this function unless you explicitly specify a parameter type at the function call, since you don't use the typename `U` as a function argument.  I suspect you want to do something like:

```
template <typename U>
void tf(pointer<U>);
```